# If Globalization & Localization with resource files having diverse affect with Google indexing and searching of website content etc?

Tags: html, asp.net, seo, globalization, google-search-console

I have developed a [site](http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/Home)  with globalization & localization using resource files and i have my website content in resource files but not in HTML of site pages(i mean not hard code text on html pages) so i wonder to know if Google can reach out my website and will detect website content.
as i know we always hard code our content in html pages of website and its good for Google and SEO purposes but in my case all content comes from resource files to web pages.

here is my html code on web page looks after i use resource files

```
<div class="apiculture">
                <div class="post_content">
                    <p><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, QueenBeeAnatomyText1 %>" /></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="apiculture">
                <div class="post_content">
                    <p>
                      <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, QueenBeeAnatomyText2 %>" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am not having hard code content in my html but all content comes from resource files with name of content tags etc etc as you can see from above pasted code clearly.

if its good for SEO purposes or not as i have unique and very good content for my site?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

ASP is a server-side language. The file will be processed server-side prior to being served through the web server. Google has absolutely no clue what is going on behind the scenes, all it sees is the final HTML. In your browser, choose View → Source (or similarly named), *that* is what Google and anybody else sees.